# Title: ESP8266 Keeps Flashing Blue Light and Rebooting—How to Fix?

Tags: esp8266

I am working on a project using ESP8266 with MicroPython. After flashing the firmware, the blue light on the board starts flashing incessantly, and it keeps rebooting.

I've tried erasing and re-flashing the firmware using esptool, but the issue persists.
I expect the board to boot up normally, without flashing lights or reboots.
(Supplement: You can connect using putty, but it’s all gibberish)

Comment: The "gibberish" is boot messages from the ESP8266. The bootloader outputs messages at 74880bps. Set your terminal program to that speed and they shouldn't be garbage anymore. The messages it outputs should shed some light on why it's restarting.

Answer (score 1):

Check if D4, D7 and D8 are disconnected from any peripherals. These pins are needed for flashing/writing the firmware. Having a signal on these pins while flashing the firmware can trigger a reset in the chip. So try flashing with these pins disconnected.

Regards
Dario

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I can make sure that no other devices are connected.
(Supplement: You can connect using putty, but it’s all gibberish)